# Determine $M$ in an inequality of absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

> Given $a < \dfrac{\pi} {2}$. If $M < 1$ with $|\cos x - \cos y| \leq M|x-y|$ for every $x, y \in [0,a]$, then compute the value of $M$

I have no idea to approach this problem (come from real analysis olympiad in my state) , but my friend said that we should use intermediate value theorem in real analysis. Too bad I don't have much experience to apply that theorem. Could you help me? Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that if $f$ is differentiable in the interval $I$

- $f $ is Lipschitz $\iff f'(x)$ is bounded in $I$

and

$$M=\sup\{|f'(x)|, x\in I\}$$

See the related [Is a function Lipschitz if and only if its derivative is bounded?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165431/is-a-function-lipschitz-if-and-only-if-its-derivative-is-bounded) and [Prove that if $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f$ is Lipschitz, then $f$ has a bounded derivative.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723821/prove-that-if-f-is-differentiable-on-a-b-and-f-is-lipschitz-then-f-ha?rq=1)

Comment: $f'(x) = -\sin x$ and the supremum of its derivative with a given interval is zero. So, $M = 0$?

Comment: @ShaneDizzySukardy ops sorry there was a typo, it is |f'(x)| of course!

Comment: $M = 1$ that's it?

Comment: @ShaneDizzySukardy Yes it is, note that we can derive directly the result by MVT since $|\cos x - \cos y| = |f'(c)||x-y|$ and from $|f'(c)|\le M$ we obtain $|\cos x - \cos y| \le M |x-y|$

Comment: But it says that $M < 1$, does not it contradict?

Comment: @ShaneDizzySukardy Oh yes sorry of course, with this condition sup$(f'(x))=\sin a$.